# angles on the celestial sphere

Tags: coordinate, declination, mathematics, right-ascension

This is a somewhat simplified, and drawn / formulated in a manner more targeted to astronomy, version of a diagram and a question that I've also posted in [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2949028/50256).

In the diagram below I depict:

- the celestial sphere with the North Celestial Pole (NCP), the South Celestial Pole (SCP) and the celestial equator
- a latitude circle at latitude $\delta$ (declination)
- two points $A$ and $B$ on that latitude circle
- the center of the celestial sphere $O$ and the center of the latitude circle $O'$

[image]

My question is:

Given angle $\phi$ between the rays $OA$ and $OB$, what is the angle $\theta$ between the rays $O'A$ and $O'B$ ? I am trying to derive $\theta$ given $\phi$ and $\delta$. Observe that if $A$ is the first point of Aries, then the angle $\theta$ is the Right Ascension of a star located at point $B$.

My assumption is that the following formula holds:

$\phi = \theta*cos(\delta)$

Comment: I think you are correct, but suggest using spherical coordinates to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

This answer in [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2949040/50256) provides the correct relationship between $\theta$ and $\phi$. And [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2950640/50256) supplies the proof.